# Why does date.today() return time as well?

Tags: python, date, flask

In Flask, when I define a slug in a class (for mongoengine), and I want to return 2014-04-11 (YY-MM-dd), I always get `YY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` as slug.

Why is it so?

When I remove the slug variable, my demo variable returns the right format...

```
class Post(db.Document):
    demo = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())
    slug = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

And this is how an example URL looks like hence:

`http://0.0.0.0:5000/2014-03-19%2000:00:00/`

Comment: not sure why alecxe deleted his answer ... its exactly right ... `datetime.date.today()` only returns a date ... but a dateTime Field must have a time, since it doesnt it defaults to 00000

Comment: @JoranBeasley haven't paid attention that it's a flask-related question :) (not django)

Comment: meh its still built on alchemy so almost certainly the answer remains the same

Comment: So the right usage would be to use `db.StringField(default=datetime.date.today())`, right?

Comment: @JoranBeasley well, `MongoEngine` is used here, there is no `DateField`..

Comment: Yes, and StringField does not work either, because only strings are excepted...

Comment: why not do 
`import re;s=str(db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())); match=re.search(s, r"\w+\-\w+\-\w\+");slug=match.group(0);`

Comment: @MartinBetz Make a new function, return `str(datetime.date.today())` and use this function as the default with `StringField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTimeField` always returns a full date with time formated as `hh:mm:ss`.

To get only the date, you should change the database field to string.
This is how your class should look like hence:

```
class Post(db.Document):
    demo = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())
    slug = db.StringFieldField(default=datetime.date.today())
```